# Custom permalink gives 404 error only in some pages

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, localhost, windows

Some pages of my Wordpress don't work after creating a custom permalink for products URL in my localhost environment. Home page works, but for example /contact page returns 404. If I look at Apache log, it appears a 404 from /contact. My environment is with WAMP and Windows 10.

I have tried the most common things I have read like:

1. Enable mod_rewrite.
2. Modify httpd.conf with:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Reset permalinks to default and change back as desired.
4. Delete .htaccess.
5. And also:

   ```
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```

mod_rewrite is enabled, Wordpress have permission to edit .htaccess and if I delete .htaccess and recreate permalinks, htaccess is created again.

My permalinks are %parent_category% and %keyword%, so URL for products are: .../parent_category/keyword/product-name.

For %parent_category%, I get the parent category of the product (WooCommerce) and for %keyword% I get it from Yoast SEO keyword field of the product.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was because I wasn't writing a product base. So, after writing a product base like /product/%parent_category%/%keyword% everything worked fine. Besides, I used a plugin called Woocommerce Permalink Manager to remove the "product" from the URL.